# Tailwind config for packages in monorepo

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite, monorepo, pnpm

I am trying to create a monorepo using Vite, React, TailwindCSS and pnpm ([repository here](https://github.com/hamez0r/vite-react-tailwind-pnpm-monorepo)).
My tailwind config files are under src/apps/app. When using the `Page` from src/packages/feat-page, the tailwind classes are ignored. unless I add `"content": ["../../**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"]`, in the config under src/apps/app, but I'm trying to figure out if there's a better approach.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Don't create a global config file. If you have any sharable styles or common configurations use [preset](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/presets) instead.

Then use same preset for all packages you're using Tailwind.

Answer (score 1):

You can, BUT DON'T, create a global config file. Instead, create a config file inside each project or app that uses tailwind independently.

But if you have some shared theme styles or plugins that you need to share across multiple apps and packages, then the better approach is to create folder `tailwind` inside `packages` folder, create a `package.json` file, then add and manage the theme and plugins from there. This way, you import what you need from them in the app or package that is using tailwind.

---

**Note**: the same applies when you configure prettier, eslint and typescript. You need to do it per project. But, unlike tailwind, you can create some shared configs at the global level and import them.

Comment: I want to place features under src/packages/feat-something, and other functionality under src/packages/shared-something. These packages will use tailwind, but it seems cumbersome to add tailwind config files in each of these. This answer is useful, but I'm still looking for a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to share it across a lot of packages in your mono, and they all use the same theme etc, the way I do it is have one global, and import that file into the other tailwind.config.js files.

Ie:
shared tailwind-config package:
package.json (has the tailwind and postcss dependencies)
tailwind.config, has all the themeing etc.

then in the other packages, have another tailwind.config file and with one line just do an import and export from the shared package

this would be the tailwind config in one of the web apps / packages / image file, what ever:

```
module.exports = require("../../packages/tailwind-config/tailwind.config.js");
```

In your main tailwind config, you will need to add all the different paths, but, because you are importing it, you might only need a couple of different lines in the content, I usually only need one because I keep the src/** file structure in the packages.

```
content: ["./src/**/*.{tsx,ts,js,jsx}"].
```

There is one catch, if you are using next and using transpile packages, you will need to modify that content array to be relative to your packages/apps.

It builds fine with a lot of different packages and supports hot reloads in dev.

Preset is probably the best way to do it, but this is faster and im lazy :)